# How do I Turn off 'smart tags' in access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've found and article for Access 2007 on Improving speed of the database (http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/help-access-run-faster-HA010235589.aspx), one of the options is to 'turn off smart tags if you don't use them'. I am unable to work out where I would do this in Access 2010. Are these still used in 2010? Are they called something else? Where do I turn them on or off?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options in Access that allow you to enable or disable smart tags: one to show smart tags on forms, and one to show smart tags on datasheets.

**To enable or disable smart tags in forms, do the following:**

- On the Tools menu, click Options.
- In the Options dialog box, click the Forms/Reports tab.
- Select or clear the Show Smart Tags on Forms check box.

**To enable or disable smart tags on tables in Datasheet view, do the following:**

- On the Tools menu, click Options.
- In the Options dialog box, click the Datasheet tab.
- Select or clear the Show Smart Tags on Datasheets check box.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa206129(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa206129%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Jatin, the documentation you have provided is unfortunately for Access 2003, I'm looking for the option in MS Access 2010